# how do I choose a lock name when performing PHP side locking

Tags: php, mysql, multithreading, locking

So I have this code:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (id, field1, field2) VALUES ($id_insert, $field1, $field2)");
$id = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'));
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field3 = $id WHERE id = $id");
```

My question is...Is there a risk for a mysql deadlock when running this code, if so why is that the case?

Now I can do a PHP side locking but I will need a unique identifier for the lock. What are some guidelines in choosing a unique lock identifier name? How do I go about choosing a lock name that will properly prevent MySQL deadlocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you can use mysql LOCKING feature:

```
mysql_query("LOCK TABLES table WRITE"); // You need to use WRITE lock in your case
```

Then execute your queries:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (id, field1, field2) VALUES ($id_insert, $field1, $field2)");
$id = mysql_result(mysql_query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()'));
mysql_query("UPDATE table SET field3 = $id WHERE id = $id");
```

Then Release the lock

```
mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES");
```

Note1:
For a complete reference use [Mysql Locking Concepts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html)

Note2:
Using `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, I suggest check out [PDO_MYSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)